# Chrome extension update - Chrome Web Store system error

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When i upload an update to my extension on chrome developer dashboard,
it is unable to do so and it shows,

```
An error occurred: Failed to process your item. Chrome Web Store system error, please try again later.
```

I updated the extension version in the manifest from 0.103 to 0.104, the manifest version is unchanged (2). As i made a change that did not require any extra permission, i did not make any further changes to manifest.json. The only file changed is plugin-min.js

I tested it locally on my computer as well before uploading

contents of my zip file:
 - icons (folder)
 - plugin-min.js
 - manifest.json

The total size of the zip file is 20.6 KB.

Any clue as to what changes are required ?

Comment: No changes required. As indicated by the error, it's an internal error of CWS systems, and expected to be transient. Just, you know, _try again later_.

Comment: @Xan - I thought so as well, checked after nearly 20 hours later. Still the same error. Should i wait more or look for anything else now >

Comment: This is a good place to ping the CWS devs: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-extensions

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This behaviour seems to happen especially if you're logged in with more than one Google Account at the same time.

[Google recommends](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/faq#faq-gen-16) logging out and back in with the account you want to use to publish your app or extension.

> #### When I try to upload my app to the Chrome Web Store, I get this error: "(Server rejected) An error occurred: please try again later." What gives?
>
> This error occasionally occurs if you've been logged into the Chrome Web Store for a long time. If you sign out of your Google Account and then sign back in, you should be able to upload your app.

Comment: Didn't worked for me. Made two attempts still not working for me getting the message as below again.

Chrome Web Store system error, please try again later.

Comment: Thanks ... finally it worked for me after clearing browser cache and browser restart.

Comment: Thanks! Tried another browser, and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a bug if you have never accepted the terms of service on the [Chrome Developer dashboard page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard). After visiting that page, and accepting the terms, then this error went away for me.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, the issue occurred due to multiple accounts being logged, which is usually the case with chrome web dev, at same time.

Just opening in incognito session worked for me and later it asked to set 2-steps authentication mandatorily.