# Chrome Web Store system error, please try again later

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to deploy a script ad add-on but I get the following error: "Chrome Web Store system error, please try again later."

I've already waited 12+ hours but unfortunately this didn't help.
I get the error after I fill in the first screen (description, url, instructions,...).

Comment: An answer to the same question seems to have been provided in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257589/chrome-extension-update-chrome-web-store-system-error).

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Were you able to find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This was very unclear from the documentation but you have to pay $5 to register as a developer in the Google Developer Console

[image]

I found this information from [this Google form](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6018&q=Chrome%20Web%20Store%20system%20error%20please%20try%20again%20later&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner) about this same topic.

Answer (score 1):

To me problem was that **I hadn't accepted the term of services** in [Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard)

You do not have to pay for the $5 fee to overcome this if you are developing for your own domain (google app)!