# Error when uploading Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Has anyone encountered this error when attempting to upload to the chrome store?

Package is invalid. Details: 'Could not load JavaScript 'scripts/scraper.js' for content script.'

Any direction would be appreciated,
Cheers

Comment: Could be due to a weird zip format, try another packer. Could be wrong letter case of file names. Actually, there could be more reasons. Shows us the file you're trying to upload.

Answer (score 1):

You may probably want to first try the suggestions in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257589/chrome-extension-update-chrome-web-store-system-error). As mentioned in the thread, Google doumentation recommends logging out and back in with the account you wan to use to publish your app or extension. Also, you might need to also accept the terms of service on the [Chrome Developer dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard).

In addition to that, I also found about a similar issue in [Google Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/9_KDyk6Ju-4) wherein it was mentioned that there has already been a filed bug which you can star for you to receive email updates. This is a bit old issue but, checking the thread, it hasn't been resolved yet.